# Unable to verify links to jobs from the sidebar

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

When I click on a job in the sidebar on `https://stackoverflow.com/`, I get this:

[image: something went wrong page]

I didn't feel that optimistic about getting a new job, but I did assume I would get *a little* farther along in the process before I got rejected.

Was it something I said?

Comment: You used the word "vacation" in your profile text. V-word is a big no-no when looking for jobs. Who wants employees who want *vacation*?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Oops, good point. I'm back from vacation now, so I should probably change that. (There, I fixed it.)

Comment: Reading my comment a second time it was maybe not entirely clear I was joking! But always good to have an updated status :)

Comment: Sorry, I was just playing along. ;) I _do_ actually want to work somewhere that lets me leave sometimes, though. (That reminds me, I should probably turn my out-of-office autoreply off on my work email. Maybe later...)

Comment: Thanks for the report, we're investigating

Comment: Yup, my bad. Fix+explanation incoming

Comment: Clicks should be working now (reverted a build). Still working on fix+post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fix is going up.

TL;DR: I made a mistake, didn't test (oops), and a typo made it to Prod.

---

TS;WM:

When we generate URLs for job ads, we sign them and append a `sig=` querystring parameter to the URL, which we then use during the clickthrough to validate that the URL hasn't been tampered with. If the validation fails, you get the page shown in the question up there.

I recently made a change to the validation code, and in a supreme derp moment.. I failed to test it before pushing to Prod (boooooo hissssss I know). Unbeknownst to me, I had a wrong value for the initializer in a for loop:

```
-  for (var i = 0; i < max; ++i) // <- wrong
+  for (var i = offset; i < max; ++i) // <- right
```

This essentially caused the `IsValid` check to return `false` for... well... *everything*.

So yeah.. totally my screw up. Apologies. Next round of virtual beverages on me.

PS: I'll also be adding some automated tests to ensure this doesn't happen again.